# How to completely destroy Mongo database created by docker-compose?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, containers

I am using `docker-compose` to create a MongoDB service. Here is how it looks:

```
services:
  database:
    image: 'mongo'
    environment: 
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=azunyan
    volumes:
      - ./container-scripts/mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js
      - ./data/db:/data/db
```

I build and run the service using `sudo docker-compose up --build -d database` and this creates the MongoDB container.

During testing I add a few collections to the database by connecting to the database through `mongo <container ip address>` and issuing a few mongo commands (e.g. `db.createCollection()`)

Afterwards, I use `sudo docker-compose down -v` to remove the container, and I also run `sudo docker system prune -a -f` just to be sure. I expect that the next time I build and run the image, the database should be empty (i.e. have no collections), however I can see the collections are still there. Why? How do I get a clean MongoDB container?

Comment: You're storing the actual data in `./data/db` on the host; are you doing anything with that directory?

Comment: Not at the moment, but even if I remove that folder, I can still see the collections

Comment: Try remove the folder then do docker-compose up -d --force-recreate. If that doesn't help you could try docker-compose down. Any anon or named volumes belonging to the compose project will be destroyed with it.

Comment: I assume you don't want to prune mongo-init.js via `docker system prune -a -f --volumes`?

Comment: If you still see the collections even after removing the data folder then the data folder you think you are using is not the actual folder in use.

Comment: If you can get a mongoshell into the database of the running container you can see where mongo thinks the data files reside by issuing the command `db.serverCmdLineOpts().parsed.storage.dbPath`

Comment: Apologies, I think you guys are right, I just needed to remove the folder. Not sure what happened when I first tried it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to delete your data directory and then destroy and recreate your database container.

```
docker-compose down
rm -rf ./data/db
docker-compose up -d database
```

Note: You do not need the `--build` flag as you are referencing a pre-build image in your docker-compose file. You also don't need to specify the `database` service unless you have other entries within your compose file that you didn't add to the example. You also don't need `docker system prune`.

Comment: Can you explain more why I don't need `docker system prune`?

Comment: So the command you use `docker system prune -af` will delete stopped containers, unused networks, unused images that don't have containers associated to it, and build cache. If you were to run `docker system prune -af --volumes` it still wouldn't help in your case because you are mounting `./container-scripts/mongo-init.js` and `./data/db` from the file system and not a named volume managed by docker.